# C# - ToString() versus + ""

Tags: c#, string

In C#, coding:

```
int a = 10;
string myString = a.ToString();
```

it's equal to coding:

```
int a = 10;
string myString = a + "";
```

?

Comment: the latter will implicitely call `a.ToString`.

Comment: End result yes, how you'll arrive there no: http://goo.gl/X9XIm4 . By using the `+` operator you are calling the `string.Concat` that will then call `int.ToString`